# Node.js: node-postgres native raise error SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm on Window 11 with Node.JS 20 and PostgreSQL 15.1:

```
import { native } from 'pg'; // npm install pg pg-native
const pool = new native.Pool({ .. });
pool.connect();
```

pool.query raise error

```
SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above
```

How fix it?

library version

```
{
  "pg": "^8.11.3",
  "pg-native": "^3.0.1"
}
```

Comment: What versions of pg and pg-native? **Add information to question text**. Best bet it is the interaction of `pg-native` and `libpq` that is causing  the problem. To verify try a connection without `pg-native`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver pg 8.11.3 and pg-native 3.0.1

Comment: Have you tried without `pg-native`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes. without pg-native it works! But i want 'pg-native' also on my dev pc, because i use pg-native on the serve for better performance

Comment: Then the error message is telling you the problem, the version of `libpq` `pg-native` is linking to is to old to recognize the new SCRAM authentication.